# RadCombobox getting disabled when populated with data

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I'm working on an asp.net application that uses the telerik radcombobox which I'm not familiar with. The issues I'm facing is that all the radcombobox in the app get's disabled as soon as they are populated with data.

I find it very strange that when there are no items in a combobox it anabled. Please will you share some light here.

This will be enabled:

```
<radC:RadComboBox TabIndex="2" ID="RadComboBox1" Enabled="true" runat="server" Height="300px" Skin="WindowsXP" SkinsPath="~/RadControls/ComboBox/Skins" AutoPostBack="True"  OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="next" Width="50%" ></radC:RadComboBox>
```

This will be disabled:

```
<radC:RadComboBox TabIndex="2" ID="RadComboBox1" Enabled="true" runat="server" Height="300px" Skin="WindowsXP" SkinsPath="~/RadControls/ComboBox/Skins" AutoPostBack="True" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="next" Width="50%" >
<Items>
  <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="RadComboBoxItem11"  runat="server" Text="Item1" />
  <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="RadComboBoxItem1" runat="server" Text="Item2" />
</Items>
</radC:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it right. I've added controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" on pages tag, in the web config file.

I had the following:

```
<pages styleSheetTheme="Main">
  ...
</pages>
```

Changed to:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" styleSheetTheme="Main">
  ...
</pages>
```

Comment: That's quite odd. Did you try providing different values for the Value property of each item? Also, are you using the latest version (Q1 2015 SP1 at the moment)?